# Can I take a specific element in the string and store it in the variable after using RegEx?

Tags: python, regex

I'm currently using RegEx in Python to remove the underscores from a string, shown below:

```
def function_renamer(code):
    
    newcode = re.sub('[_](.)', lambda x: x.group(1).upper(), code)
```

After that I'd like to find the words that had underscores to store them into a variable. Is it possible for me to do that? For example:

```
function_renamer("def a_random_function(x):")
>> "def aRandomFunction(x):"
```

Then store the changed string "aRandomFunction" in a variable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use something like:

```py
import re

results = []

def replace_me(m):
    x = re.sub(r'_(.)', lambda z: z.group(1).upper(), m.group())
    results.append(x)
    return x

def function_renamer(code):
    return re.sub(r'\b[^\W_]+(?:_[^\W_]+)+\b', replace_me, code)

print(function_renamer("def a_random_function(x):"))
print(results)
```

See [Python proof](https://tio.run/##ZY7NCsIwEITveYrFiwmWgHgriI/hwWpIm1ULzQ/bBKovX6NGPbinZWZ35gu3ePVuM8@9DZ4iEDJGOKYhjrCFw5Exg@eshkF3qCxyK2oGeaZsE8oxtZyWikuxrGDQtjUa7jXc5YV8CnwtZAoBiYsKbNGEeAWUFqmz7wyfPmpM5GB6956T62LvnSJ02uaYzhssAOXyy9C0h1OzV8cV39WqrGLVtJnrh1/BK4GxQL2L/C9/8WzVirQz3qqPneHqRcZ@PxVwMc8P).

**Results**

```
def aRandomFunction(x):
['aRandomFunction']
```

**Expression expanation**

```
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  \b                       the boundary between a word char (\w) and
                           something that is not a word char
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  [^\W_]+                  any character except: non-word characters
                           (all but a-z, A-Z, 0-9, _), '_' (1 or more
                           times (matching the most amount possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  (?:                      group, but do not capture (1 or more times
                           (matching the most amount possible)):
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    _                        '_'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    [^\W_]+                  any character except: non-word
                             characters (all but a-z, A-Z, 0-9, _),
                             '_' (1 or more times (matching the most
                             amount possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  )+                       end of grouping
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  \b                       the boundary between a word char (\w) and
                           something that is not a word char
```

Comment: Great, that's exactly what I was looking for. Can the RegEx also be modified so that if there are multiple "aRandomFunction" in the string it's only stored in the variable once?

Comment: @RDTJr `results = set()` and `results.add(x)` ([proof](https://tio.run/##dY/NasMwEITveooll6yIEYTcDKWP0UPcCtnatAbrh7UETl7eURIlPZTuadlZvpmJ5/QT/GFdRxcDJ2ASgmnOU5rhDWZKKIWwdCpCnMxA2hE62Qoos5QPJjXnHnmrUcltA5NxvTVwaeGivjnkiHupcozEKBtw9SblHVCNlLEWl@cpZfawPExP2Q9pDF4zeeMKYwiWqnv9fAXo@uNX96E/d/je6rrKXdeXUL/ZG7gThIg8@oR/@Jubq9FsvA1OP@USroXs/9U2pc8DWBvJdb0C))

Comment: Fantastic. Sorry for all these questions, I'm a novice when it comes to RegEx. Is it possible to capitalize the string so it becomes "ARandomFunction"? Also for strings such as "_a_random_function" can I keep the first underscore?

Comment: @RDTJr Try [this code](https://tio.run/##dY/NasMwEITveooll2gbIyi9mYY8Rg5xImRr0wqsH2QJXL@8qyZKewjVScwsM9@Er/Tp3du6Ght8TBCJsUhTHtMEe5gocWRM07UYYVQDSUvcYsugvLlcRBJT7nnc8sP7/nSRZ5Rc4LaBUdleK1haWMRH9DnwVxQ5BIocG7BVQzGoYJIazUIc8RZb64XSms8PKeXoYL6jXLMbkvFORnLKlsDBa6pM9fIXq@vly@nSHeV5xw@trF/cdX1h/NvUwC2DsRCNS/ypYfPTq2RUTnsrH3bBayG7/z2QT/qmrLyX1J24rt8).

Comment: One very last inquiry, is it possible to capitalize the "a" in "_aRandomFunction" if you don't mind?

Comment: @RDTJr Use more capturing groups [as in this code](https://tio.run/##dY/LasMwEEX3@orBm8w0RtB2ZxryGVnEiZBtpTVYD2QJXJd8u6umirsI1Wq4d9A54z7DhzWvy9JrZ30ArxjzaoxDGGEHowpIjHXqkgo3yFYJrVBTxSC9KW14xcfYoN/g/m13PIsTCeS0KWGQuukkzBXM/N3b6PCZeHROeaQSLsWXXuPrOr8Qb6Xrgxz6WSFdC7qBshCXXYfTPQrRG5h@5S7RtKG3RnhlpE6I1nYqW@bNVbRuUDwRHs/1QZy2uK9EHmlLdZPM/y4t4fYPY873JuADpfhhS@Gl6awW9zopVhDN/x2Ih7wgypB8Ky3LNw).

Comment: Hi sorry to bother you again, everything is working but I'd also like to take out an element in the set to use it for another function. I've tried ```results.pop()``` and ```results_list = list(results)``` to extract elements but I've been unsuccessful.

Comment: @RDTJr `pop()` works, see [the code](https://tio.run/##dVG7asMwFN31FcKL722Coe1mGjJ17dohDyFb163BeiDL1E3It7tKKjtDqabLOYfzQO47fFrzPE2tdtYH7okxT/3QhZ5veE8BkDFFTSRcJ2sSmkBjyXh8Y1R4KvqhAp/D9mWzO4oDCigwX/NO6kpJfir5qfjwdnDwiMXgHHnANW@ys17gy3I/YVFL1wbZtScCvGR4C0qFCqkUjDMUBm/4@FuuGUwdWmuEJyN1jKitotQyKZei@wrEA8LuuH8XhxVsS5FOXOG@is3vS9f85sOY860J8Cclu2ZL4aVRVouZjhVLPpj/OS7@4BliCklbkfVWk2gD6c0831kHs6zJ3@jr@j8lPyf@kt/J1zF4WQdS/OoQNYtbVE3TDw).